# Is it possible to create a custom lifecycle in svelte 3?

Tags: svelte

I need to perform a check (eg is login is true) before rendering a page.
In vuejs there is the 'beforemounting' event, but it does not exist in svelte.
therefore I would like to create or emulate such an event, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Technically everything inside the `script` block is executed at component instantiation, before mounting. Additionally as the [documentation](https://svelte.dev/docs#beforeUpdate) states `beforeUpdate` will run before the first mount as well.

So, given this code:

```html
<script>
  import { beforeUpdate, onMount }

  console.log('instantiating')

  beforeUpdate(() => console.log('beforeUpdate'))
  onMount(() => console.log('onMount'))
</script>
```

the output would be

```
instantiating
beforeUpdate
onMount
```

Answer (score 0):

I expressed myself wrong: I intended to create or manage an event before creating the component (as in vue.js there is the "beforeCreate" event), before rendering the component and then eliminating it, if certain conditions are not true